# exposing host's docket socket in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I need to run mocha tests in GitLab CI a few test need to interact with docker daemon, to operate on containers, run, create , etc.. I'm trying to avoid using docker in docker for reasons in [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) article and trying his proposed solution with official [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` has the following code.

```
test-runner:
  stage: test

  # docker image is based of Alpine Linux - https://wiki.alpinelinux.org
  image: docker:stable
  tags:
    - docker
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    # expose docker socket to GitLab CI
    - docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker
    # install required packages
    - apk add nodejs npm git zstd
    - git config ....
    - git submodule sync --recursive
    - git submodule update --init --recursive

  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test
```

I keep getting the following error, how to fix this?

```
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I ended adding the services field with `docker:dind` to expose the socket.

```
   test-runner:
      stage: test

      # docker image is based of Alpine Linux - https://wiki.alpinelinux.org
      image: docker:stable
      services:
        - docker:dind
      tags:
        - docker
      variables:
        GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
      before_script:
        # install required packages
        - apk add --no-cache bash
        - apk add nodejs npm git zstd docker
        - git config ...
        - git submodule sync --recursive
        - git submodule update --init --recursive

      script:
        - npm ci
        - npm run test
```